# To find the least possible value of $c$

Tags: quadratics

suppose $f(x) = -x^2 + bx + 1$ and and $g(x) = x^2 + 2x + c$ are such that
$max \quad f(x)\le min\quad g(x)$ as $x$ varies over the set of real numbers. The least possible value of $c$

what I tried is to the maximum value of $f(x)$ and minimum value of $g(x)$ and apply the given inequality. But  I am getting an equation in $c$ and $b$ and I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: When I worked through the problem, I found an inequality relating $b$ and $c$, but the important thing to note was that there was a $b^2$ term, which cannot be any less than $0$ for any value of $b$, so to proceed you are able to set that equal to $0$ and solve for $c$.

Comment: sorry that was a typo. it is actually $c$

Comment: thanks I was stuck whether to put $b$ = 0 or not but now it is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $g(x) = x^{2} + 2x + c = (x^{2} + 2x + 1) + c - 1 = (x+1)^{2} + c - 1\geq c - 1$. Moreover, $f(x) = -x^{2} + bx + 1 = (-x^{2} + bx - b^{2}/4) + b^{2}/4 + 1  = -(x-b/2)^{2} + b^{2}/4 + 1 \leq b^{2}/4 + 1$. Hence we may conclude that $c$ must satisfy the following inequality:
\begin{align*}
\max f(x) = b^{2}/4 + 1 \leq c - 1 = \min g(x) \Leftrightarrow c\geq b^{2}/4 + 2\Leftrightarrow c_{min} = b^{2}/4 + 2
\end{align*}
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f''(x)<2$ thus $f(x)$ at critical point is always a local maxima
$$f'(x)=-2x+b\tag{x=b/2 is critical point}$$

Similarly, on the same lines, $g(x)$ at critical point is always a local minima
$$g'(x)=2x+2\tag{x=-1 a crital point}$$

$$f(\frac{b}{2})\le g(-1)$$
$$-\frac{b^2}{4}+\frac{b^2}{2}+1 \le -1+c$$

Therefore $$c \ge\frac{b^2}{4}+2$$

Comment: I have reached till here. But the answers are numbers. and I don't how how to proceed beyond this step.

Comment: See, $b^2$ has to be positive, thus you may put $b=0$ to conclude your answer as $c=2$? @biswaprakashmishra

Comment: yes I got it. I was stuck what to do with the RHS of the inequality